# Redirect making a PATCH request instead of GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

I'm making an ajax patch request from my application.js file:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "PATCH",
     url: "/units/" + id,
     data: { 'var_1': var_1,
             'var_2': var_2,},
     success:function(){
            alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
     },
     dataType: "text"
 });

 // stop normal form submission behaviour
 $("#add_form").submit(function(e){ return false; });
```

This request is successfully received by my controller, and the attributes of my object are updated. I then try to redirect to an index page with a particular id.

*units_controller.rb*

```
if @unit.update_attributes( ** data ** )
    flash.notice = "Successfully updated "
    redirect_to :controller => "/units", :action => "index", :id => params[:id]
end
```

My issue is that the redirect_to call contains a PATCH method request and therefore returns a routing error. It should be just a GET request, as per my routes.rb file:

```
resources :units, except: :show
get '/units/index' => 'units#index'
```

Any idea why my redirect_to call contains a PATCH method request and how to change it to a GET?

Comment: try " redirect_to units_path "

Comment: how can you possibly redirect in an ajax request? What do you expect your browser to do?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your issue?

Answer (score 7):

"If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303. See Other status code which will be followed using a GET request." taken from the API documentation of [ActionController::Redirecting#redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to).
Btw. redirecting in that situation is not an appropriate solution. You better should render an appropriate template or just only update the resource instead of all resources(if possible).