# Redirecting in before_filter and go on with original request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

In my app I use OAuth to authenticate in other sources, so that I need to keep their tokens for each user. I store tokens in entities I call `openids`. In that way, I want to check if openid is valid (token is not expired) before creating and updating some models' objects. If token is expired, I want to redirect user to logging in and then go on with the action that was interrupted by login (creating, updating, etc).
My idea was to save `request.fullpath` in cookies and then, when the authorization is over, in the method that called when callback of login method initiated, redirect user to previous action by using `redirect_to cookies[:auth_back_path]`.

The thing is for example, `update` method needs PATCH request to be called. `redirect_to` provides only `GET` methods.

So that in one of the controllers I have (`ones_controller.rb`):

```
before_filter :check_openids, except: [:relogin, :show]

....

def check_openids
  unless current_user.openid_actual?
    cookies[:auth_back_path] = request.fullpath
    redirect_to '/auth'
  end
end
```

Can, please anyone tell, how can I make it in a right way? I really want to realise how it all's going.

P.S.:
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357734/6014860) that force doing `patch` or `delete` (when I will call `destroy` method) is not a good idea.

Comment: I am not getting you what you what to do in that ??

Comment: @TusharPal Probably I'm not clear enough. I edited the post anf hope now it's more clear

Comment: It's doesn’t matter of put delete because it ultimately a type of method but the action is fixed like update edit so please check your condition before it

Comment: @TusharPal To be honest, I don't understand what you mean :( To call `delete` method I need to send `DELETE` request to (in that case) `/one/[:id]`. So the thing is I can't, 'cause `redirect_to` sends only `GET`. In that case instead of `delete` `show` action is called.

Comment: redirect_to action: "show", id: 5
redirect_to post
redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_to articles_url
redirect_to proc { edit_post_url(@post) }

Comment: above are difrrent way to call it